# syntax error, unexpected ''supplier_rule' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) prestashop

Tags: prestashop

i just uninstalled a module on my local prestashop 1.5 development server,and recieved following error,

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''supplier_rule'    
' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\override\classes\Dispatcher.php on line 26
```

now i can not even access backend? i just tried to uninstall a module and this happend? Any solution?

---

Update:

Here is the code at including line 26;

```
    class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
    {
        /**
         * @var array List of default routes
         */
 line 26        'supplier_rule' => array(              
                'controller' => 'supplier',
                'rule' =>       'supplier/{rewrite}/',
                'keywords' => array(
                    'id' =>             array('regexp' => '[0-9]+'),
                    'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*', 'param' => 'supplier_rewrite'),
                    'meta_keywords' =>  array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                    'meta_title' =>     array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
                ),
            ),
    .........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well known bug/situation in PrestaShop.

PrestaShop tries to manually copy class methods to `\override\classes\*` files, and sometimes the lines miss-match or the line break are wrong, and the end result is incorrectly copied lines which cause syntax errors. That happens both on installation and uninstallation. Basically, you then have to manualy fix/remove syntax errors from overriden class files.

What you need is to log on to FTP server and edit this files - fix syntax error.

EDIT:

If you had uninstalled the module, then you should replace the contents of this file with:

```
class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{

}
```

Please check that the are no `public function ...` because if there is, it means that other modules may have inserted their functions here. It there aren't any, then it's safe to reset the file with the code I above.

Comment: Just copy paste it here or on pastebin.com if it's long, we'll take a look.

Comment: please check above, i edited the question and inserted the code snippet

Comment: gskema, it worked but now some of the modules that i already installed are also de-listed when i go got modules section in the back office. Does this have any thing to do with other modules.

Comment: What do you mean de-listed? Maybe they were depended on this module that you have just uninstalled, so they uninstalled too (just guessing).